# Karate: Karate-summary report missing CSS format

Tags: report, karate

I am running Karate tests in a pipeline in Gitlab CI. When I am providing karate-summary.html in artifact path (eg. target/karate-reports/karate-summary.html) and then I open that file after the pipeline runs, it is missing all CSS formatting like below:

[karate-summary.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPI66.png)

I am currently providing the target/karate-reports as artifact path. But with that, I always have to download the whole zipped folder (karate-reports), extract it and then open karate-summary.html which now has all CSS formatting

My question is how can I get karate-summary.html directly in artifacts with all CSS formatting so that I don't have to download a zipped folder and then open that karate-summary.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry the official answer as of now is "write your own report" that said, you can track (or even better contribute to) this open issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2132